# Swift nested JSON Objects not decoding

Tags: json, swift, decode

I'm trying to decode an array of nested objects within Swift and it's not working. The nested objects are of the same type which I'm using Realm to store the values and look like:

```
struct myObject: Codable {
  var name: String?
  let otherObjects = List<myObject>()
  var events: [String]?
  ...
  if let objects = try container.decodeIfPresent([myObject].self, forKey: .otherObjects) {
        otherObjects.append(objectsIn: objects)
    }
}
```

**Decoder Function** - This works for all other fields inside the object at top level including events which is an array of String.

```
static func decodeResponse<T:Codable>(_ response : Any?) -> T? {
    if let response = response, let dict = response as? [String:Any]  {

        var dictionaryToParse = dict
        var arrayToParse: [[String:Any]]?

        if let dataObject = dict["data"] as? [String:Any] {
            //sometimes the response has an outer "data" OBJECT
            dictionaryToParse = dataObject
        } else if let dataArray = dict["data"] as? [[String:Any]] {
            //sometimes the response has an outer "data" ARRAY
            arrayToParse = dataArray
        }

        do {
            guard let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: arrayToParse ?? dictionaryToParse, options: []) else { return nil }
            let obj  = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
            print("DECODE: \(obj)")
            return obj
        }
        catch let error {
            print("ERROR: (decodeResponse): \(error)")
            return nil
        }

    }
    return nil
}
```

The coding keys map as they're the same type and nothing gets outputted as an error.

Comment: Why do you use append instead of assigning directly? Are you sure you are not appending to nil?

Comment: @Sulthan - I'm using Realm to store the values.